# Live database of checksums of all files on Wikimedia Commons

Tags: api, wikimedia-commons

Wikimedia Commons is a database of 25,000,000+ freely usable media files to which anyone can contribute.

Contributing a file to Commons takes some work (creating metadata, description, selecting categories), and it fails if the file has already been uploaded by someone else (or by forgetful me in the past).

So, a database of all checksums of Commons files would be very useful, to compare before working on metadata.

Is there such a database?

- Free
- Reasonably up-to-date, though I can bear with a week or so of delay
- API to quickly request whether a particular checksum is already on Commons or not
- No need to download the whole database before being able to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikimedia Commons has developed a special API exactly for this, with the keyword `aisha1` which stands for "All Images with a given SHA1".

## API usage

Let's say you want to check whether your file myimage.jpg is already on Wikimedia Commons or not.

1. Calculate the checksum of myimage.jpg, for instance your get `801957214aba50cb63bb6eb1b0effa50188900ba`
2. Launch a request to https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allimages&aisha1=801957214aba50cb63bb6eb1b0effa50188900ba
3. You receive a JSON response
4. In this JSON, if `allimages` is empty then myimage.jpg has never been uploaded to Wikimedia Commons. If it has, you receive a reference to the existing image, example:

JSON:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "allimages": [
            {
                "name": "Commons-logo-beta.png",
                "timestamp": "2010-05-19T22:21:32Z",
                "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Commons-logo-beta.png",
                "descriptionurl": "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Commons-logo-beta.png",
                "descriptionshorturl": "https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=10378437",
                "ns": 6,
                "title": "File:Commons-logo-beta.png"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Alternatively, there seems to be a different approach with the same goal: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:User_scripts/File_Analyzer

Answer (score 2):

I think [Elog.io](http://elog.io/) meets your requirements or at least comes close. Some background on how they use checksums to find similar images is [in this blog post](http://commonsmachinery.se/2014/09/digital-image-matching-part-2-finding-similar-hashes/)

Comment: Nice! This repository has "hamming distance" "blockhashes" to find images that are extremely *similar*. I am looking for checksums to identify the *exact* same image, which is probably easier than this. Anyway, great resource, I will use it if there is no database of exact checksums.

Comment: I think the parent project, Commons Machinery, has that database of exact checksums. All their code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/commonsmachinery).

Comment: Could you please make another answer about that database of exact checksums? I haven't been able to find it (or a live hosted API to it) on their website nor on their Github. All projects I have found seem to involve hamming or perceptual distances. Thanks!

Comment: I just asked directly: https://twitter.com/EvoMRI/status/604372934258466816 .